# selectOneRadio set value as index of selected item

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want my `p:selectOneRadio` to have value of index of selected radio button.

For example, rows in `p:dataTable` can be aware of their index using attribute `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"`.

So my question is, can individual radio buttons in `p:selectOneRadio` be aware of their index? Then i could do something like this

```
<p:selectOneRadio itemIndexVar="index" value="#{bean.selectedIndex}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" var="item" itemValue="#{index}" itemLabel="#{item.label}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

EDIT:

If i specify items manually, i can indeed set itemValue to represent index of that item, see below.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{formBean.selectedIndex}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="First item has index 0" itemValue="0" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Second item has index 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Third item has index 2" itemValue="2" />  
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

This would make my `p:selectOneRadio` to have value corresponding to index of selected radiobutton.

I want to do the same thing, but using `f:selectItems` tag instead of multiple `f:selectItem`

Comment: Can't you just use `<p:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item" selection="#{bean.selectedItems}" rowKey="#{item.id}"><p:column selectionMode="single" />`? See also showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

Comment: You don't need any `<p:selectOneRadio>` then. The selected items can be (pre)set in `selection` attribute. Have you looked at the showcase link?

Comment: using datatable would either make my radiobuttons stacked vertically (as on showcased page)... or is there any way around it?

Comment: maybe i should clarify, that i dont have problem with (pre)selecting items. What i want, is for my selectoneradio (or possibly other) component to have value attribute set to index of selected object.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. What exactly is the concrete functional requirement? I understood selecting a single table row by radiobuttons in a column.

Comment: I edited the question. Question had nothing to do with table, i only used datatable as example - since its rows can be aware of their index (by index i mean position of the item in collection). I want my selectItems be also aware of their index, so i can use this index as itemValue. Usually, people want itemValue to be object from collection, but i want itemValue to be index (position in collection) of that object.

Comment: I still don't understand your concrete problem. What problem exactly are you facing? What problem exactly are you trying to solve? Replacing those three `<f:selectItem>` tags by a single `<f:selectItems>` tag? Then you should show the code of your attempt on that. This has further completely nothing to do with setting the "index".

Comment: It has everything to do with index, since the only problem i am trying to solve is to get index of selected item in selectoneradio. My functional requirement is to be able to get INDEX of selected item (in selectoneradio) from my backing bean.